# Add html to all content before a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, this is a real shot in the dark and not too sure if I phrased my title correctly but what i'm trying to do is as follows:

I have an html table that looks like this

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Type: Tanker </td>
      <td>DWT: 8672.82 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Flag: Gibraltar</td>
      <td>Pumping Capacity: 12 Cargos pumps each 200m3/h </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is wrap all content "headers" in a strong before the ":" in a  dynamically so the table looks as follows

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><strong>Type:</strong> Tanker </td>
      <td><strong>DWT:</strong> 8672.82 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><strong>Flag:</strong> Gibraltar</td>
      <td><strong>Pumping Capacity:</strong> 12 Cargos pumps each 200m3/h </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I understand that i could achieve this easily by adding two more columns to the table and using css :first-child and nth-child selectors but this is not the way I want to go about doing this due to size / layout constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it easily like this :

```
$('td').html(function(_,h){
    return h.replace(/([^:]+):/, '<strong>$1:</strong>')
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/befun/3/edit)

Comment: Humm, I was going to post like your edited one, but previous code I liked. May be better to include both.

Comment: @C-link Here it is : http://jsbin.com/befun/1/edit I personally prefer the regex version but somebody ill at ease with regular expressions might prefer the splitting.

Comment: Nice... I was thinking something like the regex way.  The other one is new to me...good logic there.  No point posting a new answer,  both your answers are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should take a look to `definition lists`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp

They seem to be semantically appropiate for your type of table, and by providing separate HTML tags for the term and definition fields (type, tanker; dwt, number; etc.) will help you define CSS styles easily.

A possible new HTML structure may be:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Type</dt>
    <dd>Tanker</dd>
    <dt>DWT</dt>
    <dd>8672.82</dd>
    ...
</dl>
```

Note: I didn't put the `:`, you can add them using the `:after` meta-selector in CSS. Again, in css you may indicate that all `dt` tags be rendered in bold fonts.

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer the question of how this can be done in jQuery, it does highlight the fact that the HTML is wrong to begin with.